# Simple Text Analysis library for C

Tags: c++, c

I'm in the midst of creating my school project for our programming class.
I'm making a Medical Care system console app and I want to implement this kind of feature:

When a user enters what they are feeling. (Like they are feeling sick, having sore throat, etc) I want the C Text analysis library to help me analyze and parse the info given by the user (which have been saved into a string) and determine the medicine to be given. (I'll be the one to give which medicine is for which, I just want the library to help me analyze the info given by the user).

Thanks!

A good example would be this one:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32175/Lucene-Net-Text-Analysis

Unfortunately it's for C#

Update:
Any C library that can help me even for the simple tokenizing and indexing of the words? I know I could do it by brute force coding... But a reliable and stable api would be better. Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is what is known as an [Expert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system). This is not a trivial thing to implement.

Comment: Your general language interpretation problem that you describe is [Natural Language Processing  (NLP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), and there are softwares like the ones listed on [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits). But NLP is a tough problem, and I think for your problem (and what @MikeBantegui describes, an expert system/decision engine is tougher still) you could cheat with some string parsing and word matching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analyzing natural language text is one of the most difficult problems you could possibly pick.

Most likely your solution will come down to simply looking for keywords like "sick" "sore throat", etc - which can be accomplished with a **simple dictionary of keywords and results.**

As far as truly "understanding" what the user typed though - good luck with that.

**EDIT:**

A few technologies worth pointing out:

Regarding your question about a lexer - you can easily use **flex** if you feel you need something like that. Probably faster (in terms of execution speed AND development speed) than trying to code the multi-token search by hand.

On Mac there is a very cool framework called **Latent Semantic Mapping**. There is a WWDC 2011 video on it - and it's awesome. You basically feed it a ton of example inputs and train it on what result you want. It may be as close as you're going to get. It is C-based.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_mapping

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/TextFonts/Reference/LatentSemanticMapping/index.html

Comment: Don't you mean 'sore' throat?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - LOL, yes - copied from question. Good thing you aren't a computer - or you'd be totally confused!!

Comment: @steve, indeed it is difficult but is there any C library that can help me even for the simple tokenizing and indexing of the words? I know I could do it by brute force coding... But a reliable and stable api would be better. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Hahaha! I haven't noticed that one.. I just updated the texts

Comment: @Raven - in english, words are usually separated by spaces. A simple split and loop, a regex, or a substr function is good enough. You don't need a full-on lexer unless you really want it. If you did though, **flex** is a good option - and produces C code.

Comment: @Steve who says I'm not a computer? Haha

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - If you were I'd pay for your API :)

Comment: +1, I just learned about Mac OSX's latent semantic mapping library.

Comment: Thanks man! I've learned a lot :) ... I'll just have to study this flex library so that I could use it on my project.

Comment: IMHO, for natural language processing lex is overkill. A plaintext tokeniser can be handcrafted in <100 lines of plain C.

Comment: @wildplasser - I never understand when people say things like that. As  a colleague developer, I'd much rather edit your lex file than your custom parser... and I highly doubt your < 100 line parser is going to match the speed of lex's with a bunch of string literal terminals. It's like saying "gcc" is overkill - huh?

Comment: In Natural language, there *are* no string literals (or *everything* is a string literal). And nowadays, everything runs at busspeed.

Comment: @wildplasser - That's unintelligible. Your own answer lists 18 string literals. And who cares if inefficient code runs as bus speed? That's like saying "I'm busy being lazy"... it's oxymoronic. Slow code running 10x faster than it used to will still be slower than the alternative - it's just being slower faster.

Comment: The only advantage of lex is the usage of the DFA to solve conflicts between keywords with common prefixes. For the rest most of its work is just basic equivalence classes (whitespace, alphabetical, numeric, interpunction) which can just as easily be handled in a hand coded lexer. And that certainly is not slower. I rest my case.

Comment: @wildplasser - a DFA taking into account all possible tokens will absolutely be faster than splitting each string, looping through each possibility and checking for equivalency. Absolutely nothing will be faster than a DFA for that. Including your hand-written parser unless you implement it as a DFA - and if you do, you just wasted all your time when flex can build that for you in a much more maintainable fashion. It's patently incorrect to claim that a DFA's only advantage is in resolving conflicts.

Comment: FIY: I added a code snippet to my reaction, just to illustrate my point. (note: lex needs *at least* one table lookup *per character*)

Answer (score 1):

This is what [wakkerbot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/) makes of your question. (The scores are low, because wakkerbot/Hubert is all Dutch.)
But the tokeniser seems to do fine on English:

```
[   6]:        |    29/ 27|  4.792 | weight |
------|--------+----------+---------+--------+
 0  11|  15645 |    10/ 9 | 0.15469 |  0.692 |'to'
 1   0|  19416 |    10/10 | 0.12504 |  0.646 |'i'
 2  10|  10483 |     4/ 3 | 0.10030 |   0.84 |'and'
 3   3|   3292 |     5/ 5 | 0.09403 |    1.4 |'be'
 4   7|  27363 |     3/ 3 | 0.06511 |    1.4 |'one'
 5  12|  36317 |     3/ 3 | 0.06511 |   8.52 |'this'
 6   2|  35466 |     2/ 2 | 0.05746 |   10.7 |'just'
 7   4|  12258 |     2/ 2 | 0.05301 |   0.56 |'info'
 8  18|  81898 |     2/ 2 | 0.04532 |   20.1 |'ll'
 9  20|  67009 |     3/ 3 | 0.04124 |   48.8 |'text'
10  13|  70575 |     2/ 2 | 0.03897 |    156 |'give'
11  19|  16806 |     2/ 2 | 0.03426 |   1.13 |'c'
12  14|   5992 |     2/ 2 | 0.03376 |  0.914 |'for'
13   1|   3940 |     1/ 1 | 0.02561 |   1.12 |'my'
14   5|   7804 |     1/ 1 | 0.02561 |   2.94 |'class'
15  17|   7920 |     1/ 1 | 0.02561 |   7.35 |'feeling'
16  15|  20429 |     3/ 2 | 0.01055 |   3.93 |'com'
17  16|  36544 |     2/ 1 | 0.00433 |   4.28 |'www'
```

To support my lex/nonlex tokeniser argument, this is the relevant part of wakkerbot's tokeniser:

```
for(pos=0; str[pos]; ) {
    switch(*sp) {
    case T_INIT: /* initial */
        if (myisalpha(str[pos])) {*sp = T_WORD; pos++; continue; }
        if (myisalnum(str[pos])) {*sp = T_NUM; pos++; continue; }
        /* if (strspn(str+pos, "-+")) { *sp = T_NUM; pos++; continue; }*/
        *sp = T_ANY; continue;
        break;
    case T_ANY: /* either whitespace or meuk: eat it */
        pos += strspn(str+pos, " \t\n\r\f\b" );
        if (pos) {*sp = T_INIT; return pos; }
        *sp = T_MEUK; continue;
        break;
    case T_WORD: /* inside word */
        while ( myisalnum(str[pos]) ) pos++;
        if (str[pos] == '\0' ) { *sp = T_INIT;return pos; }
        if (str[pos] == '.' ) { *sp = T_WORDDOT; pos++; continue; }
        *sp = T_INIT; return pos;
     ...
```

As you can see, most of the time will be spent in the line with `while ( myisalnum(str[pos]) ) pos++;`,
which catches all the words. myisalnum() is a static function, which will probably be inlined. (There are similar tight loops for numbers and whitespace, of course)

UPDATE: for completeness, the definition for myisalpha():

```
static int myisalpha(int ch)
{
   /* with <ctype.h>, this is a table lookup, too */
int ret = isalpha(ch);
if (ret) return ret;
        /* don't parse, just assume valid utf8 */
if (ch == -1) return 0;
if (ch & 0x80) return 1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems nice.. Isn't it for python? or is there any C implementation? Thanks!

Comment: No only plain C. (Python is for ...) wakkerbot at sourceforge. The correlations an the above table are bad, because wakkerbot normally suppresses highfrequency words (they are likely to be stop words) That is the reason that {'i', 'the' ,'and', 'be', 'this'} are in this list. After a few hundred words of training, they will probably drop out of the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There's a C++ Data science toolkit called MeTA - ModErn Text Analysis Toolkit.  Here's follow the features:

- text tokenization, including deep semantic features like parse trees
- inverted and forward indexes with compression and various caching strategies
- a collection of ranking functions for searching the indexes
- topic models
- classification algorithms
- graph algorithms
- language models
- CRF implementation (POS-tagging, shallow parsing)
- wrappers for liblinear and libsvm (including libsvm dataset parsers)
- UTF8 support for analysis on various languages
- multithreaded algorithms

It comes with tests and examples. In your case I think statistical classifiers, like Bayes, will perfectly do the job, but, you can also do manual classification. It was the best feat to my personal case. Hope it helps.

Here's the link https://meta-toolkit.org/

Best Regards,